# FeatureSpacePlot output differs in documentation vs. a notebook

Tags: machine-learning, documentation

I was exploring this first example of `FeatureSpacePlot` and it shows some strange behavior. On the left is the documentation window and to the right is the notebook. The same example outputs different results when evaluated in the help window and the notebook window. The `b` is behind the `h` on the notebook side (rhs) and is not visible.

What could be an explanation for this?

Thanks for your help in advance. I am using v12.2.0 on Win7-x64.

[image]

Comment: Moreover, any `Method` produces the picture from the documentation. The same issue with the next example (cats&dogs).

Comment: It looks correct to me. Note that rasterization is platforum/computer dependent. Therefore, you are not using the exact same images than they used in the documentation (you can see subtle differences if you look closely), and that is why the result is slightly different. Still, contextually, it seems correct (h and n are close together, l and i are close together and so on).

Comment: `rasterization is platform/computer dependent` ... but I am on the same computer evaluating these using the same commands. Why would `Alphabet[]` get rasterized differently? For the second comment, using `Method->"Linear"` for both scenarios (docs/notebook) still produces a [different](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xc2IJ.png) result.

Comment: @Syed, sorry, I was not paying attention that you evaluated also the code in the documentation. Nevertheless, please see my answer for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default font size in documentation is different than in your notebook. For example, in my case, it is 13 in the notebook and 12 in the documentation. (You can go to the menu `Format > Font...` to get these numbers; there is probably a programmatic way to get them, but I can't figure it out now).

To convince you, just rasterize one letter in both of them, and see that the image will be different.

```
(* Documentation *)
Rasterize["a"] // ImageDimensions
(* {11, 24} *)

(* Notebook *)
Rasterize["a"] // ImageDimensions
(* {12, 26} *)
```

Therefore, to get the same results in both cases, you have to match both styles.

```
imgs = Rasterize[Style[#, FontSize -> 12]] & /@ Alphabet[]
FeatureSpacePlot[imgs]
```

[image]